# Laravel 4 redirect to modal after form validation failure

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, modal-dialog, laravel-routing

I am having a problem with a modal after validation. I have the form validation in the route like so:

```
Route::post('projects/contact', function()
{
      $rules = array(

            'contactname' => 'required',
            'yourEmail' => 'required|min:8|email',
            'whatsup' => 'required|min:10',
      );

      $validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);


    if($validation->fails())
    {
        return Redirect::to(URL::previous())->withErrors($validation)->withInput(); //This is where it's not working
    }

    else
    {       

      $fromName = Input::get('contactname');
      $fromEmail = Input::get('yourEmail');       

      $toEmail = 'exampley@gmail.com';

      Mail::send('projects.contactmailer', array('data' => Input::get('whatsup'), 'email' => Input::get('yourEmail')), function($message) use ($toEmail, $fromName, $fromEmail)
      {

      $message->to($toEmail)->cc(array('example' => 'example'));

      $message->from($fromEmail, $fromName);


      });

      return Redirect::to('/');

    }

});
```

I am using ZURB Foundation instead of Bootstrap. The form will validate fine, because it will redirect and won't send the email and the error code I have in place will show on the main page. I guess my question is, is should this form be submitted via AJAX instead of using the normal submit function in Laravel? Or can I do it the way I have it, and have it reopen the modal to show the errors from validation? I'm not extremely familiar with AJAX, and most of the examples I have seen with modals use it.

If I fill out the form, it will send the email and work exactly like it is supposed to. It's just the modal validation that I can't seem to figure out.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Have you tried Redirect::back() ?

Comment: Yes, but that still won't open the modal back up where the form is.